# Am I properly using my input file with convert?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have a list of images in a file that looks like

```
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 10:00:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:45:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:30:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:15:02.jpg
```

I want to add these images to a animation. I usually do that by using this command.

```
convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 /home/myuser/timelapse/2016*.jpg /home/myuser/animation.gif
```

However if I want to add images from say the last ten. I have the latest 10 file names in my file and I try to use this command

```
convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 < "$(< list.txt)" /home/myuser/animation.gif
```

I get

```
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:45:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:30:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:15:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 09:00:02.jpg  
/home/myuser/timelapse/2016-03-16 08:45:02.jpg  : No such file or directory
```

Is it possible the space in the file name is creating the problem? How would that be corrected?

Am I properly using my input file with convert?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use input file list with convert is to use "@"

here is the example that works for me

```
convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 @newfile.txt /home/myuser/animation.gif
```